# How te create a new column with values matching conditions from different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a simple function (both on pandas or numpy) to create a new column with `true` or `false` values, based on matching criteria from different dataframes?

I'm actually trying to compare two dataframes that have the column `email` and see, for example, which emails match with the emails on the second data frame. The goal is to print a table that looks like this (where `hola@lorem.com` it's actually both on the first and second dataframe):

```
| id | email | match |
|:------|:------ |:-------|    
| 1 | hola@lorem.com | true|
| 2 | adios@lorem.com | false|
| 3 | bye@lorem.com | false|
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you need to provide MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a contributor here to help you out

Comment: It depends how you want to match the values between the two dataframes. Per ID? Globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df1 = df1.assign(match=df2["email"].isin(df1["email"]))
```

Comment: There is no point in using numpy.where here... nor assign

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use the function `isin`:

```
df1['match'] = df1['email'].isin(df2['email'])
df2['match'] = df2['email'].isin(df1['email'])
```